# Affine algebra of an algebraic group

Tags: definition, algebraic-groups

From what I understand there are two approaches to defining an algebraic group. One can start talking about varieties and the Zariski topology and such and get to a definition of an algebraic group. One can also define an algebraic group as a (representable) functor from the category of $k$-algebras to the category of sets.

If one chooses the functorial definition of an (affine) algebraic group $G$, what is the definition of *the affine algebra of $G$*?

Comment: The $k$-algebra representing that functor?

Comment: Actually, an affine algebraic group is a representable functor from the category of $k$-algebras to the category of sets _that factors through the forgetful functor $\textbf{Grp} \to \textbf{Set}$_.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: That makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By affine algebra I assume you mean the coordinate ring, as in $\mathbb A^n$ has coordinate ring $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$.

Given an affine group scheme $G$ over $k$ there is a natural homomorphism $G \simeq \hom_k(A, -)$ where $A$ is some $k$-algebra.  By the Yoneda lemma the algebra $A$ is unique up to isomorphism and the coordinate ring of $G$ is defined to be $k[G] = A$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. After studying a bit more on this, your answer seems like the right one.